# Next Router was not mounted in my next app built with electron

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, server-side-rendering, router

I've created a npm package using nextjs and typescript to share a report module of my online app to my offline app. I created a simple page with `Link` tag to route on Click of a button and that Simple Page gets shared completely fine with the offline app's layout etc & even the translation works fine. But when I tried to share this (Next js online app) page to my electron (Next js Offline app) which has same layout structure & code,
it throws this error - Next Router was not mounted.
I have read the docs and even modified my code a bit like, adding router.isReady event to check if it was initialized before mounting, making sure it's inside a functional component but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps someone could explain it to me or guide me in the right direction.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me understand why is it still throwing error.

Here's the Page that I want to share through the package (This page has nested component), What this page does is, when someone goes to "/reports", we make a API call and fetch the reports from our DB and list it on this reports/index.tsx page. The way the table is created is through the "NewReportTable" Component & the API call is done through the "useRequestUtilities" Custom Hook which is at the top and gets invoked first -

pages/reports-index.tsx -

```
import { ReactElement, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useRequestUtilities from '../../components/hooks/use-request-utilities';
import UserLayout from '../../components/layouts/user-layout';
import { NextPageWithLayout } from '../_app';
import ReportTableSkeleton from '../../components/loading/report-table-skeleton';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import PageContainer from '../../components/users/page-container';
import { NewReportDetail } from '../../components/new-reports/models/new-report-detail';
import NewReportTable from '../../components/new-reports/new-report-table'; // Nested component

const ReportPage: NextPageWithLayout = function () {
  const {
    fetchWrapper,
    logoutUser,
    nextJsRouter: router,
  } = useRequestUtilities();
  const refetchReports =
    typeof router.query.refetch === 'string'
      ? router.query.refetch
      : router.query?.refetch?.at(0);
  type viewScreenType =
    | 'loading'
    | 'reportsAbsent'
    | 'reportsPresent'
    | 'responseError';
  const [viewScreen, setViewScreen] = useState<viewScreenType>('loading');
  const [responseErrorMsg, setResponseErrorMsg] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState<NewReportDetail[]>([]);
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const fetchReports = useCallback(async function (Refetch = false) {
    async function handleResponse(response: Response) {
      const resJson = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        const newReports: NewReportDetail[] = resJson?.reports;
        if (newReports.length) {
          if (Refetch) {
            setData(newReports);
          } else {
            setData((old) => {
              const uniqueNewReports: NewReportDetail[] = [];
              newReports.forEach((newReport) => {
                if (
                  old.find((report) => report.id === newReport.id) === undefined
                ) {
                  uniqueNewReports.push(newReport);
                }
              });
              return [...old, ...uniqueNewReports];
            });
          }
          setViewScreen('reportsPresent');
        } else if (data.length < 1 && newReports.length < 1) {
          setViewScreen('reportsAbsent');
        }
      } else {
        if (response.status === 500) {
          setResponseErrorMsg(t('error.something_went_wrong'));
        } else {
          const errorMsg =
            typeof resJson?.message === 'string'
              ? resJson.message
              : resJson?.message?.at(0);
          setResponseErrorMsg(
            `Error ${response.status}: ${errorMsg || response.statusText}`,
          );
        }
        setViewScreen('responseError');
      }
    }
    function handleError(error: any) {
      setResponseErrorMsg(t('error.something_went_wrong'));
      setViewScreen('responseError');
    }

    fetchWrapper({
      url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL_V1}/reports`,
      includeAuthToken: true,
      handleResponse,
      handleError,
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    if (!accessToken) {
      logoutUser();
      return;
    } else {
      const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
      if (userInfo?.role !== 'LabEngineer') {
        router.replace('/users');
        return;
      }
      fetchReports(Boolean(refetchReports));
    }
  }, [refetchReports]);

  if (viewScreen === 'loading') {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="py-4 px-6 flex items-center justify-between border-b border-gray-300 font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800">
          <div className="bg-gray-300 rounded-full w-20 h-5 animate-pulse" />
        </div>
        <ReportTableSkeleton />
      </>
    );
  }
  if (viewScreen === 'reportsAbsent') {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="py-4 px-6 flex items-center justify-between border-b border-gray-300 font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800">
          {t('reports.report_list_page_title')}
        </div>
        <div className="text-center w-full mx-auto pt-16">
          <h1 className="font-medium text-2xl leading-6 text-gray-800 mb-4">
            Looks like you haven&apos;t generated any reports yet
          </h1>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  if (viewScreen === 'responseError') {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="py-4 px-6 flex items-center justify-between border-b border-gray-300 font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800">
          {t('reports.report_list_page_title')}
        </div>
        <div className="text-center w-[512px] mx-auto pt-16">
          <h1 className="font-medium text-2xl leading-6 text-gray-800 mb-4">
            {responseErrorMsg}
          </h1>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="py-4 px-6 flex items-center justify-between border-b border-gray-300 font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800">
        {t('reports.report_list_page_title')}
      </div>
      <NewReportTable data={data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ReportPage;

ReportPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <UserLayout>
      <PageContainer>{page}</PageContainer>
    </UserLayout>
  );
};
```

This is a custom hook we created to make API calls. This component is under components/hooks/use-request-utilities.tsx -

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function useRequestUtilities() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const logoutUser = useCallback(() => {
    localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
    localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    localStorage.removeItem('applicationKey');
    router.push('/login');
  }, []);

  const fetchWrapper = useCallback(async function (props: {
    url: RequestInfo | URL;
    method?: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE';
    includeAuthToken?: boolean;
    body?: any;
    contentType?: string;
    applicationIdentifier?: string;
    initiate?: () => any;
    handleResponse: (response: Response) => any;
    handleError: (error: any) => any;
    handleFinally?: () => any;
    applicationKey?: string;
  }) {
    const {
      url,
      method = 'GET',
      includeAuthToken = false,
      body,
      initiate,
      handleResponse,
      handleError,
      handleFinally,
      applicationKey,
    } = props;
    const options: RequestInit = {
      method,
    };
    if (includeAuthToken || body) {
      const headersInit: HeadersInit = {};
      options.headers = headersInit;
      if (body) {
        if (body instanceof FormData) {
          options.body = body;
        } else {
          options.headers['Content-Type'] =
            props.contentType || 'application/json';

          options.body = props.contentType ? body : JSON.stringify(body);
          const applicationKeyFromStorage =
            localStorage.getItem('applicationKey');
          if (!applicationKeyFromStorage) {
            options.headers['x-api-key'] = applicationKey;
          } else {
            options.headers['x-api-key'] = applicationKeyFromStorage;
          }
        }
      }
      if (includeAuthToken) {
        options.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
          'accessToken',
        )}`;
      }
    }
    if (initiate) {
      initiate();
    }
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);

      if (includeAuthToken && response.status === 401) {
        return;
      }
      handleResponse(response);
    } catch (error) {
      handleError(error);
    } finally {
      if (handleFinally) {
        handleFinally();
      }
    }
  },
  []);

  return {
    nextJsRouter: router,
    logoutUser,
    fetchWrapper,
  };
}
export default useRequestUtilities;
```

and lastly my "NewReportTable".tsx -
Not sharing this code since it's just a Basic React-Tanstack table. But this page has no next/router imported or any code related to route. It does call the hook but only the fetchWrapper callback.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the `app` directory? If so, you need to import the router from `next/navigation` instead of `next/router`.

Comment: I'm using pages directory. I tried using next/navigation but I get a new error about app router invariant any idea what that means?, because from my understanding we need a root layout in app & i'm sitll using the getLayout pattern from pages docs only the report page that i'm exporting is using the next/navigation while the rest of the pages use next/router. Would I have to migrate all the pages to app? along with the layouts & translation? P.S. i saw the new app docs and they have a separate middleware file for translation etc.. and i'm using i18n , react-i18next  for current translation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by refactoring the code to receive router as props, my current code was creating multiple instances.. so i just made wrapper component with router as props and passed it down to children so they are dependent on the props and won't rely on other app's i.e. package app's router instance. sorry about the extended code but now each page has it's own router instance. which is better because i want to be able to share only parts i.e. pages (few whole pages with deeply nested components) of my app.